# lower bound on trace

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I want a lower bound on following trace

$trace (\bf E^T\bf F^{-1} \bf E)$

where $F$ is positive definite.

I need something that does not involve inversion of $F$.

I have found following bound, but it does not help me very much, does anybody have anything better than this?

$trace (\bf E^T\bf F^{-1} \bf E)\geq \frac{(trace (\bf E^T\bf E))^2}{trace (\bf E^T\bf F \bf E)}$

Comment: Any condition on $E$?

Comment: Is $E$ a square matrix?

Comment: @JohnMa no nothing

Comment: @user1551 no :(

Answer (score 3):

** I am not sure if this is correct **

For any two positive semi-definite matrices $A$ and $B$, you have $$\mathrm{trace}\{AB\}\geq \sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_i(A)\lambda_{N+1-i}(B)$$ where $\lambda_1(.)\geq\dots\geq\lambda_N(.)$ are the eigenvalues in decreasing order. I can't find a easy proof anywhere, however you can find a general result [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959090062H). Define $A=F^{-1}$ and $B=EE^T$ (note that $B$ is positive semi-definite). Then \begin{align}\mathrm{trace}\{F^{-1}EE^T\}\,&\geq\, \sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_i(F^{-1})\lambda_{N+1-i}(EE^T)\\&=\,\sum_{j=1}^{N}\lambda_j(F)\lambda_{j}(EE^T)\end{align}The second step follows because $\lambda_i(F^{-1})=\lambda_{N+1-i}(F)$

Comment: Thank you, I have thought of something similar, but unfortunately my $F$ here is sum of two matrices like $F=P+D$, where $P$ is a known positive definite matrix and $D$ is a diagonal positive definite matrix. Thus I can't find the eigenvalues of $F$ in terms of eigenvalues of $P$ and $D$ and that is a problem !

Comment: You can try using interlacing theorems on sum of eigenvalues on top of these.